# Generate APK from Ionic Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

```
> cordova.cmd build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Newsoft\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Please can any one help me. 
I need to generate build APK from Ionic Angular project 
but they have a problem for android environment 
and sdk root I setup Android Studio with all configuration but the error is still.

Comment: Do you have Android studio installed? There is plenty of guidance to get the required software installed for building here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android

Answer (score -3):

**step1:** Your Java Jdk file path not set correct (ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) )

**step2:** subprocess cordova.(Your environment setup is wrong so set correct setup)

**step3:**[follow this link](http://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/environment-setting-tutorial-ionic-android-on-windows/)

**step4:**[java jdk download link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

**Note:** i face same problem just now i clear